# second HDD keep turning on and off

Tags: 18.04, hard-drive

A PC of mine has 2 hard drive, 1 SSD and 1 HDD. Ubuntu 18.04 was installed on SSD and the HDD was kept as a storage data. the problem has occurred when  I try to access the HDD it just some what disconnected itself  and I can't find it from the list even checking with gpart, no show HDD on it. Is there anyway I could check what was the problem with my PC

Thanks

Comment: You can check the kernel message buffer by typing `dmesg` in a terminal and searching its output for errors. They should usually be highlighted in red and will probably mention words such as "ata" or "sd" in disk related messages. One likely cause might be a hardware defect, either a dying disk or controller, or a faulty cable.

Answer (score 0):

```
[  691.149506] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0 flags 80700
[  691.149535] ata2: EH complete
[  691.322587] ata2: limiting SATA link speed to 3.0 Gbps
[  691.322594] ata2.00: exception Emask 0x52 SAct 0x84 SErr 0x400c01 action 0x6 frozen
[  691.322599] ata2.00: irq_stat 0x0c000000, interface fatal error
[  691.322604] ata2: SError: { RecovData Proto HostInt Handshk }
[  691.322610] ata2.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  691.322620] ata2.00: cmd 60/08:10:10:08:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 tag 2 ncq dma 4096 in
                        res 40/00:10:10:08:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x52 (ATA bus error)
[  691.322624] ata2.00: status: { DRDY }
[  691.322628] ata2.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  691.322637] ata2.00: cmd 60/08:38:00:18:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 tag 7 ncq dma 4096 in
                        res 40/00:10:10:08:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x52 (ATA bus error)
[  691.322640] ata2.00: status: { DRDY }
[  691.322647] ata2: hard resetting link
[  693.531207] ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 1 SControl 320)
[  693.540877] ata2: hard resetting link
[  695.747057] ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 1 SControl 320)
[  695.749023] ata2: hard resetting link
[  697.958459] ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 1 SControl 320)
[  697.958469] ata2.00: disabled
[  697.958498] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#2 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  697.958503] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#2 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[  697.958507] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#2 Add. Sense: Logical unit not ready, hard reset required
[  697.958513] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#2 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 08 10 00 00 08 00
[  697.958517] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 2064 flags 80700
[  697.958548] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#7 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  697.958551] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#7 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[  697.958554] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#7 Add. Sense: Logical unit not ready, hard reset required
[  697.958558] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#7 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 18 00 00 00 08 00
[  697.958561] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 6144 flags 80700
[  697.958585] ata2: EH complete
[  697.958600] ata2.00: detaching (SCSI 1:0:0:0)
[  697.958629] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 2064 flags 0
[  697.958638] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 258, async page read
[  697.958648] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 6144 flags 0
[  697.958653] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 512, async page read
[  697.958818] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 2064 flags 0
[  697.958822] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 258, async page read
[  697.958854] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 2064 flags 0
[  697.958858] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 258, async page read
[  697.958886] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 2064 flags 0
[  697.958890] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 258, async page read
[  697.960629] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0 flags 801
[  697.965279] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[  700.190526] ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 1 SControl 300)
[  702.418504] ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 1 SControl 300)
[  702.426511] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  702.426516] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Stopping disk
[  702.426531] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Start/Stop Unit failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  702.460953] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp1s0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:ce84:d694:e1d3:cf9a DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=85888 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24 
[  702.460962] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp1s0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:ce84:d694:e1d3:cf9a DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=931555 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8610 LEN=24 
[  702.471075] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp1s0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:ce84:d694:e1d3:cf9a DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=85888 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24 
[  702.471082] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp1s0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:ce84:d694:e1d3:cf9a DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=931555 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8610 LEN=24 
[  704.654284] ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 1 SControl 300)
[  706.886252] ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 1 SControl 300)
[  709.106174] ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 1 SControl 300)
[  711.330213] ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 1 SControl 300)
[  713.558370] ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 1 SControl 300)
[  715.786166] ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 1 SControl 300)
[  718.022167] ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 1 SControl 300)
[  720.238131] ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 1 SControl 300)
[  722.462393] ata2: COMRESET failed (errno=-32)
```